How to set up background image to the image button in the PDF
I need to create a file picker button in the PDF document and add the background image to this button, but I don't want to resize my background image on the whole button. I need to scale the background image, but I cannot change the button size.
For instance, the button size is width: 100, height: 20, and image width: 40, height: 20, but after saving the pdf and opening it in the Adobe Reader, I have image size like a button size with width: 100, and height: 20.
The initial button field looks like , but after saving the PDF, this image looks like 
My code for creating the file picker button looks like the following:
pdButton = new PDPushButton(acroForm);
pdButton.setPartialName(field.name);
if (field.required) {
    pdButton.setRequired(true);
}
acroForm.getFields().add(pdButton);
PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
PDRectangle rect = pdfHandler.getPDRectangle(fieldRectangle);
widget.setRectangle(rect);
PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
final PDResources defaultResources = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
final PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristicForImage = createAppearanceCharacteristicForImage(pdf,
                    widget,
                    page,
                    defaultResources);
widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearanceCharacteristicForImage);
widget.setAppearance(appearance);

PDActionJavaScript javascriptAction = new PDActionJavaScript("event.target.buttonImportIcon();");
widget.setAction(javascriptAction);
widget.setPage(page);

and then I tried to set up the image to that button field:
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(defaultPdfHandler.getDoc(),
                                                MainUtils.getImageBytes(((ImageBlock) contentBlock).bufferedImage, "png"),contentBlock.name);

private void setImage(COSDictionary mk,
                          List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets,
                          int i,
                          DefaultPdfHandler defaultPdfHandler,
                          PDImageXObject pdImage,
                          COSDictionary appearance,
                          COSDictionary kid
    ) throws IOException {
        if (mk != null) {
            mk.removeItem(COSName.BG);
            PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristicsDictionary = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(mk);
            final PDAnnotationWidget widget = widgets.get(i);
            final PDRectangle rectangle = widget.getRectangle();
            PDAppearanceStream nkStream = new PDAppearanceStream(defaultPdfHandler.getDoc());
            final MainUtils.ScaledImage scaledImage = MainUtils.scaleImage(
                    pdImage.getWidth(),
                    pdImage.getHeight(),
                    rectangle.getWidth(),
                    rectangle.getHeight()
            );
            pdImage.setWidth((int) scaledImage.width());
            pdImage.setHeight((int) scaledImage.height());

            nkStream.setResources(new PDResources());
            nkStream.setBBox(new PDRectangle(scaledImage.width(), scaledImage.height()));
            try (PDAppearanceContentStream contentStream = new PDAppearanceContentStream(nkStream)) {
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0f, 0f, scaledImage.width(), scaledImage.height());
            }
            appearanceCharacteristicsDictionary.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.I, nkStream);
            appearanceCharacteristicsDictionary.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            appearance.setItem(COSName.N, nkStream);
            appearance.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            kid.setItem(COSName.MK, appearanceCharacteristicsDictionary);
            kid.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        }
    }

The debug info of this field looks like .
Can anyone help me set up the image as the background for the button with a custom size(the background image does not need to occupy the entire button area)?
